# My cron job should be running only on Sunday, but it's running on other days as well?

Tags: cron

I have a cronjob that's end goal is to make a database backup on the first Sunday of every month (and remove the previous month's backup in the process).

Here's what I have it defined as:

```
0 1 1-7 * * test `date +\%w` -eq 0 && rm /tmp/firstSundayBackup*; mysqldump -u user -ppassword database > /tmp/firstSundayBackup-`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`.sql
```

However, looking in my /tmp/ folder I'll see multiple of these backups made during the first week on days that aren't Sunday.

Shouldn't the

```
test `date +\%w` -eq 0 && REST_OF_JOB
```

stop the code from running on any day that's not Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the
>
> ```
> test `date +\%w` -eq 0 && REST_OF_JOB
> ```
>
> stop the code from running on any day that's not Sunday?

It does, but due to operator precedence this only applies to the `rm` command.  The `mysqldump` will proceed regardless.

You can fix this simply by putting brackets around the two commands, after the `&&`:

```
test `date +\%w` -eq 0 && (rm /tmp/firstSundayBackup*; mysqldump -u user -ppassword database > /tmp/firstSundayBackup-`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`.sql)
```

As a major aside: your **job** will run every day, because you've told Cron to run it every day.  Is there any good reason why you're doing this and then trying to short-circuit most of those executions, rather than just telling Cron to run it on Sundays?  That seems like the most intuitive way to approach this, so what would go wrong if you scheduled it as:

```
0 1 1-7 * 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to realize this without the test of date by relying on an [edge case](https://treats.wdt.io/cron-bug.html) in cron's implementation. Try [`0 1 1-7 * */7`](https://crontab.guru/#0_1_1-7_*_*/7)`REST_OF_JOB`